# Display Messages in Angular Application

Tags: angular, angular12

On an Angular 12 application I have a Sign Up component:

```
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private userService: UserService) { 

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
    });

  }

  signUp() {

    if (this.form.valid) {

      this.userService.signUp({email: this.form.value.email, this.form.value.password).subscribe(
        
        (next) => { 
          
        },

        (error) => {
          new FormGroupErrorBuilder(this.form).setErrors(error.error.errors);
        },

      );
    } 
  }    
}
```

If the form submission succeeds I need to show a message. Should I:

1. Hide the form and show an HTML element with the message?
   I would use a Boolean variable to hide one and show the other?
2. Should I create a Message Component just to show messages?
   In the component I would have a code for each message in my APP.
   When SignUp form completes I would redirect to Message Component's Route passing the Message Code to show the correct message?
3. Other approach?

Answer (score 1):

Better you follow the below steps and get a more convenient approach of displaying messages.

Install `ngx-toastr` and `@angular/animations` `npm` packages like this:

```
npm i ngx-toastr --save
npm i @angular/animations --save
```

Now, you need to include `toastr css` in `angular.json` file like this:

```
"styles": [
      "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
      "src/styles.css"
    ],
```

Now, you need to import `ToastrModule` and `BrowserAnimationsModule` to `app.module.ts` file like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';      
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { SignUpComponent } from './user/signup.component';    
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
  
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SignUpComponent 
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now, create a service component (`notification.service.ts`) like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';  
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
  
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotificationService {
  
  constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) { }
  
  showSuccess(message, title){
      this.toastr.success(message, title);
  }      
  showError(message, title){
      this.toastr.error(message, title);
  } 
}
```

And, finally, call `showSuccess` or `showError` method from component (`signup.component.ts`) to display the message accordingly:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';  
import { NotificationService } from './notification.service'
  
@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {      
  
  constructor(private notifyService : NotificationService) { }

  //...

  this.notifyService.showSuccess("Signup successfully!", "");

  //...

  this.notifyService.showError("Signup failed!", ""); 

  //...         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PrimeNG's toast message.

See example [here](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/toast)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Angular toast notifications for that, it has an adjustable auto disappearing feature. And it can be callable only from your observable not need for HTML.

- I would suggest you look at this Toast Notification generator, [here](https://costlydeveloper.github.io/ngx-awesome-popup/#/playground/toast-generator)
- And StackBlitz example, [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/minimal-toast-notification?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

To compare the numbers of two numeric arrays with each other, you can do the following :

```
 int[] id1 = { 1,2,3,4,5,6};
       int[] id2 = { 1,5,4,3,2,6};

        for (var i = 0; i < id1.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (id1[i] != id2[i])
            {
               //Your Code
            }
        }
```